# How do I calculate this correctly?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, sqlite, windows-10

I have a system in WPF and C# and SQLITE(this is not important here), that calculates the amount of water people drink in a day. User has the permission to alter the value of cup size in ML and the meta of the day(in this case it's not important).

The calculation of the thing is:

```
    takewatervalue = int.Parse(this.takeWater.Text) + takewatervalue;
    counter = takewatervalue * cupml;
    textCounter.Text = counter.ToString();
```

This calc works fine when people don't alter the value of cupml in another window(shown below), when they alter, this happens:
[image: alter the value of the cup screen]

example before alter the value of cupml:

```
    cupml = 200 // actual value of cupml choosen for the user

    takewatervalue = int.Parse(this.takeWater.Text)(user input = 1) + takewatervalue(0); // 
    counter = takewatervalue //1 * cupml //200; // = 200 ml -- this is right no problem here
    textCounter.Text = counter.ToString(); // showing to the user the counter and that's good
```

another round:

```
    cupml = 200 // actual value of cupml choosen for the user
    
    takewatervalue = int.Parse(this.takeWater.Text)(user input = 1) + takewatervalue(1); // 
    counter = takewatervalue //2 * cupml //200; // = 400 ml -- this is right no problem here
    textCounter.Text = counter.ToString(); // showing to the user the counter and that's good
```

But when we change the cupml, this happens:

```
    actual conter value = 400 ML
    cupml = 300 // actual value of cupml choosen for the user in another window
    
    takewatervalue = int.Parse(this.takeWater.Text)(user input = 1) + takewatervalue(2); // 
    counter = takewatervalue //3 * cupml //300; // = 600 ml -- this is not right, the right value is 600 + 400(the old counter) = 1000 ML
    textCounter.Text = counter.ToString(); // showing the wrong counter;
```

Someone knows to calculate this in another way?

the complete code for reference its here which has a database in SQLITE and other stuff, but the point here its this calculation: https://github.com/lucasbarbosagit/BebaAguaAPP

Comment: I am confused. What is `takewatervalue`? What is `counter` supposed to count?

Comment: Oh, and please don't make us download a whole project. Post a [mcve].

Comment: Im gonna try make this more clear.

Comment: I'd start by refactoring out the actual computation. In principal it must be something like `newSum = oldSum + (cups * size)` So make that a function. Write Unit-Tests for it. If the whole thing still doesn't work then, you'll know the formula is correct but you make the wrong inputs.

Comment: Should not counter = counter + takewatervalue * cupml?

Comment: @SamXia It´s not, this way the value of counter it's gonna be wrong at the second round. I just need to make this question more clear sorry.

Comment: @LucasBarbosa, the value of couter should be added not multiplied, for your example if you have 2 cup 200ml and 2 cup 300ml, the take water value should be 4 and couter should be 200*2 + 300 * 2ml, and this counter cannot be get by simple one multiply. You need another "takewatervaluecurrent" to count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you have some design issues with the way you calculate the amount of water drunk. I.e. you store the number of cups drunk without knowing what the capacity of the actual cup was. And in the meantime you can alter the size of the cup which in fact acts as if all the previously drunk cups were changed.

First of all, I'd not use the UI control's fields as storage (I'd avoid `int.Parse`).

Then, depending on the long run, I'd either have a single milliliter counter or a list of 
"drink" event where a cup capacity is stored every time a cup of water is drunk.

Thus, think about something like (I haven't compiled it):

```
public class WaterConsumption
{
    private List<int> _DrunkCups = new List<int>();

    public int CupCapacity { get; set; }

    public void DrinkACupOfWater()
    {
        this._DrunkCups.Add(CupCapacity);
    }

    public int GetTotalWaterDrunk()
    {
        return this.DrunkCups.Sum()
    }
}
```

Then the content of the upper field in your form is the result of `GetTotalWaterDrunk()` and the content of the lower field of your form has to be stored in `CupCapacity`.

Let me know if it's clear to you and if it solves your problem.

Comment: This works but where are the amount of the cups the user choose in input? Example: The user maybe can drunk 3 cups of 200 ml, not one of 200ml. But its my fault dont make this more clear.

Comment: If the user drinks more than one cup of water than simply call `DrinkACupOfWater()` more times. Or provide an overload to this method that takes the number of cups as input and internally adds enough cups to the list.

Comment: Well i think this approach is better and i remove the input of the people to choose amount of water to drink, because i guess this its a ux flaw and i change in the project. Thx